# Left margin in android studio

Tags: android-studio

Left margin in android studio, it takes so much from my screen code.

[image showing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8CSc.png)

it has nothing to do with right margin, (I've tried it, that another problem).

Please if you have any solution don't hesitate to help me.

**Solution**
File -> Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Left margin in distraction free mode: 0
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRbLq.png)

Comment: In most IDEs data such as git commits or comments are shown in these kind of spaces. Normally you are able to resize them with your Mouse.

Comment: File -> Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Left margin in distraction free mode: 0 (it was -1 "Specify -1 to use automatically calculated margin (centering the editor)", thats why the code was centered in the screen).